# java - limitation of static methods and newInstance() introspection - any workaround?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, static

So, I'm working on a custom logging/audit module for some of our java spring back-ends.

This module is used to fire all sorts of custom events that are saved to a database for later retrieval/reporting.

- "User2 registered"
- "User5 bought productX"
- "MoonLanding occurred with UserN, UserB"

all sorts of events really. each event has an event_type and an event_category and a wide variety of varying parameters.

There is a big hierarchy of EventBuilder classes which allow building all those custom events that end up in the exact same database table (using one single associate JPA Entity).
Each of those EventBuilder has a different constructor that takes different parameters relevant to that "custom event record" we are trying to build.

Now the Problem is as follow:
All EventBuilder have the 2 following method: getEventType() and getEventCategory() which are sort of meta static methods but are not declared as such. The only reason they are not declared as static is so that some introspection/reflection code can find all the EventBuilder classes, instantiate them using newInstance(), assume those 2 methods will be there (as part of an Interface always implemented) and build a list of all possible event_types, event_categories and how they relate to each other.

The problem with this is that is required those EventBuilder classes to have a default constructor so that those 2 methods can be queried and that info retrieved without having to use the real custom constructors of those object. It works but it introduces the possibility to have EventBuilder instance not initialised properly.

It seems that the 2 available options are massively flawed:

- current solution of bad default constructor (so that all those classes can be instantiated in a generic way) and 2 static methods not declared as static (so that they can be overridden in the class hierarchy)
- making the 2 methods static but now they can't be part of a java interface, they can't be overridden in the class hierarchy, the introspection/reflection code can't assume they will be there, etc.

Has anyone got a better third idea? Many Thanks!

Comment: `Has anyone got a better third idea?`  Use Log4j and forget it?  Seriously I don't know how you got anyone to buy off on this monstrous idea.  Code cost money to maintain.  There's almost no way you can justify a return on "logging."  Plus future maintainers will curse your name.  This is a no-win situation.

Comment: When code needs to discover things reflection style already, why not use annotations? Those were made to be discovered and readable but not harm the code / force certain interfaces, etc. You can even make it compatible with regular methods when you put code like `return getClass().getAnnotation(X).getValue()`  in them

Comment: Markspace, Regarding log4j. the problem is that those are events not related to usual warning/error, they are not about programming, they are project-specific business events. Also, you would have to save events in the database, with some associated json structure. Also that saving would only have to happen with certain events, not the typical logging. Can log4j be configured in such a fashion?